# Java generics array operation

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics, operators

I have a Vector generic class that contain an array of that contains elements of type T, and i want to have vector addition(for int, double, float, ... of course not boolean,... ) in my class, but i can't do "array_vector[i]", how use operator without know the type ?

```
 public class vector<T> {
    private T[] array_vector;

    public vector(){
        this.array_vector = null;
    }

    public vector(T[] array_p){
        this.array_current = array_p;
    }

    public void vectorAddition(T[] array_other){
        if(this.array_vector.length == array_other.length){
            for(int i=0; i<this.array_vector.length ; i++){
                this.array_vector[i] += array_other[i];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you say that you want to add int, double, float. Then why not specify the Type `T` like `vector<T extends Number`

Comment: Pleas use the java naming convention and use Capital case start on classnames and lowercase start on variables. Otherwise it is difficult to read. Other than that Java already has a Vector class so it might be a good idea to name your class differently.

Comment: You would need a `BinaryOperator<T>` instance to perform the addition.

Comment: vector<T extends Number> not working

Comment: Upper bounding with `extends Number` doesn't work, because `+` isn't defined for `Number`.

Comment: @AlexandreLibert you'd have to use the methods in `Number` class to do the addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly; you need an instance of `BinaryOperator<T>`:

```
this.array_vector[i] = binaryOperator.apply(this.array_vector[i], array_other[i]);
```

For example:

```
BinaryOperator<Double> = (a, b) -> a + b;
BinaryOperator<Integer> = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

Pass one of these into the constructor of `vector`, e.g.

```
public vector(BinaryOperator<T> binaryOperator, T[] array_p){
  // assign to a field.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you always use numbers, maybe it's for the best to declare T extends Number to ensure strong typing checks no matter the solution applied:

```
public class vector<T extends Number> {
```

About solutions, I think that the more similar solution to the user's case is to use instanceof checks inside the vectorAddition method:

```
        if (array_vector instanceof Integer[]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array_vector.length; ++i) {
                array_vector[i] =
                    (T)(Integer)(array_vector[i].intValue() +
                    array_other[i].intValue());
            }
        } else if (array_vector instanceof Double[]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; ++i) {
                array_vector[i] =
                    (T)(Double)(array_vector[i].doubleValue() +
                    array_other[i].doubleValue());
            }
        //} else if (array_vector instanceof ...[]) {
            // ... declare other supported types
        } else {
            // throw exception because not supported
        }
```

However maybe is better to define some binary operator classes for common Number children and autoset it in the constructor, based on the array_vector instance with something like:

```
        if (array_vector instanceof Integer[]) {
            // ...
        } else if (array_vector instanceof Double[]) {
            // ...
        } else if (array_vector instanceof ...[]) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // throw exception because not supported
        }
```

And maybe define a custom binary operator constructor if desired/needed.